# Filtering Data Table based on column values containing special charactors in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have below datatable which has data as shown below now i have to filter the rows based on column "Roles" which contains values like 55:1,55:2,55:3

Datatable look like above
[image: DataTable]

Below is the c# code that i tried to filter but it doesnt worked

```
> ADODB.Connection oConn = new ADODB.Connection();
>             oConn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\";", "", "", 0);
>             string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) + "]";
>             ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();
>             System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
>             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>             rs.Open(strQuery, "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + ";
> Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\";",
>                 ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockReadOnly, 1);
>             adapter.Fill(dt, rs);
>             
>             dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "Initial";
>             dt.Columns[1].ColumnName = "BranchCode";
>             dt.Columns[2].ColumnName = "Roles";
>             
>            
>             dt.AcceptChanges();
> 
>             //DataTable tblFiltered = dt.AsEnumerable()
>             //                 .Where(r => r.Field<int>("Roles") == 1)
>             //                 .CopyToDataTable();
> 
>             dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Roles like '%55:%'";
> 
>             return dt;
```

Comment: You don't need `>` to format your code, just 4 spaces at the beginning of each line. Use the format-button in the editor to get the correct indentation

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `LINQ`(`To-DataTable`):

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> filteredRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new {row, roles = row.Field<string>("Roles").Split('/')})
    .Where(x => x.roles.Any(role => role.Split(':')[0] == "55"))
    .Select(x => x.row);
```

That will select rows where at least one role starts with "55".

If you want to check for specific values it's even simpler (and more efficient):

```
string[] wantedRoles = {"55:1", "55:2", "55:3"};
IEnumerable<DataRow> filteredRows = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => new {row, roles = row.Field<string>("Roles").Split('/')})
    .Where(x => x.roles.Intersect(wantedRoles).Any())
    .Select(x => x.row);
```

If you want a new `DataTable` with only the matching rows:

```
dt = filteredRows.Any() ? filteredRows.CopyToDataTable() : dt.Clone();
```

Comment: I will have some records in which "Roles" column will have single value like 55:1 without " / " , so the solution that u provided is throwing object referance null exception

Comment: @selvaraj: that can't be because `String.Split` returns an array with a single string if the delimiter is not contained, so my solution should work also if there is no `/` inside.